# How do I simplify the sin of the cos of an angle?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For my calculus class, I have to simplify this problem: $y=\sin^2(\cos^{-1}(t))$, enough so that it's really easy to take the derivative of. The derivative should be $-2t$.  I really have no idea how to simplify this problem.  Any hints? I know how to do the derivative, the simplifying is the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ for all values of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Think of $\cos^{-1}(t)$ as "angle whose cosine is $t$". What is the square of the sine of an angle whose cosine is $t$? Draw a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $1$ with an angle $\theta$ whose cosine is $t$. I mean, draw a right triangle, label the hypotenuse $1$, label one of the acute angles $\theta$, and label one of the sides $t$ so that the cosine of $\theta$ is $t$. What is the third side of the triangle, in terms of $t$? What is the sine of $\theta$? Now square that and differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\cos(\arccos(t)) = t$ and $\sin(\arcsin(t)) = t$, then $\sin^{2}(\arccos(t)) = 1 - \cos^{2}(\arccos(t)) = \dots$